# How to optimize a color gradient shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have created this simple fragment shader for achieving a vertical color gradient effect.
But I find  this to be taxing for my mobile device in full screen.

is there any way to optimize this?

here is the link to the code

http://glsl.heroku.com/e#13541.0

Comment: Why not just compute the color in the vertex shader, and let the varying interpolation do the actual gradient?

Comment: I was under the impression that fragment shader is what is what is used to do with colors. Can you point me to some material which describes to do this in vertex shader. I have read it can increase performance drastically.

Comment: You use the same code in the vertex shader, then pump the varying directly into gl_FragColor.

Comment: But then how would I get gl_FragCoord  in a vertex shader ?

Comment: @user1109536: No, you can deal with colors in vertex shaders as well. Only not with the color of the final fragment. You'd define the colors for your vertices, and pass them through the varyings. Then you'll simply get the color linearly interpolated over the primitive. It doesn't get much faster than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this instead.

```
vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy);

vec4 top = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
vec4 bottom = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(bottom, top, position.y));
```

[Example](http://glsl.heroku.com/e#13542.0)

*You can further change the color yourself, I just used random colors.*

---

You can even further eliminate calculating the `x` but that's kinda overkill.

```
vec4 top = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
vec4 bottom = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(bottom, top, (gl_FragCoord.y / resolution.y)));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I will go with the second option. And also will removing unused variables in a shader code improve its fps output?

Comment: You're welcome! ... The Shader compiler itself will optimize the code and remove all non-used variables, statements, uniforms, etc. Though if you can see/know how you can optimize it yourself, it would be best to do so, and not totally rely on the Shader compiler, as things vary depending on the GPU and driver. ... Also the more you can pre-calculate the better, thereby don't send 3 matrices to the Shader and then calculate them, instead pre-calculate them and send them as the resulting matrix.