# Creating a Ramp Shader in Cgfx

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm currently stuck on a problem. Basically I want to use a ramp shader in an engine for one of my projects, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. I was advised by the support provided to try shading it using a Cgfx shader. Unfortunately, I have no idea to do this because I'm not familiar with what's happening in a ramp shader, and I'm not familiar with Cgfx shader language either.

Here's an example of a ramp shader in Blender.
[image: blender]

Here's an example in Maya.

[image: maya]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an GLSL shader that someone already posted as a gradients/ ramp shader - it  should work with NVidia's CGfx code: 
[How to optimize a color gradient shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083462/how-to-optimize-a-color-gradient-shader)

Comment: Seems this sample is in GLSL. I'll look into it to see if it fits what I'm trying to do.